# Delete single table row in a loop

Tags: java, servlets, dao

first sry if i do any grammar mistakes my motherlanguage is not English.
Here im printing out all the customers from database, and for each table row i add delete link which takes customers code as a parameter. When clicking on the link it should delete one row but it deletes all the customers with the same code, any ideas how can i delete just one row even if there are customers with same code?

```
for(Customers customer : customers)
    {
        String param = customer.getCode();
        request.setAttribute("value3",param);

        out.println(

    "<tbody><tr> "
    + "<td>"+ customer.getFirst_name()+" "+"</td>"
    + "<td>"+ customer.getSurname()+" "+"</td>"
    + "<td>"+ customer.getCode()+" " +"</td></br>"
    + " "+"<td><a href='"+request.getContextPath()+"/Search?id="+param+"'>Delete</a></td></tr>"

     );     

    dao.deleteCustomer(request.getParameter("id"));

    }
```

Deleteing method :

```
public void deleteCustomer(String code)
{
    try{
        pst = getConnection().prepareStatement("delete from customer where "
    +" code = '"+code +"'");

        pst.executeUpdate();        

    }catch(Exception e)
    {

        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {

        closeResources();
    }


}
```

Schema file :

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq1 AS INTEGER START WITH 1;

CREATE TABLE customer (
     id BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
     first_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
     surname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
     code VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
);

INSERT INTO customer VALUES(NEXT VALUE FOR seq1,'Jane','Doe','123');
INSERT INTO customer VALUES(NEXT VALUE FOR seq1,'John','Doe','456');
INSERT INTO customer VALUES(NEXT VALUE FOR seq1,'Jack','Smith','789');
```

Comment: So customers have no unique id? How can you know which customer you are deleting without a unique id?

Comment: use 'limit 1' you can delete only one record. but i think you shuld think about the question that @SalihErikci asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
pst = getConnection().prepareStatement("DELETE FROM customer WHERE code = '"+ code + "' and id IN  (select * from (SELECT MAX(c.id)  FROM customer c where code = '"+ code + "') as d)");
```

Comment: im using hsqldb, it didnt help, but deleteing with id, im using sequence for autoincrement, so how would the statement look like?     `pst = getConnection().prepareStatement("delete from customer where "
+" id  = NEXT VALUE FOR seq1 '"+id +");`

Comment: Now im getting `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: C.ID`

Comment: no more exceptions but still deletes all with same code. So it means that the id-s are all the same ?

Comment: Yes so you dont have identity field as well. Do you know the internal schema of the same?

Comment: `DELETE FROM customer WHERE id = '"+ id + "'` change method parameter to id and now works fine, thank you for your time! :)

Answer (score 2):

You should delete the customer based on their ID in the database rather than their code.

A user ID should always be unique, where a code may not be.

An example of your data might help further.